# Insufficient privileges to view Azure Kubernetes (AKS) resources which I created

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-aks

I used the Azure CLI to provision an AKS cluster. I ran the script from my computer so it ran under the scope wherein I am the principal.

So why is it that when I look at the resource in the portal, then try to look at any of its resources, I'm told that I don't have sufficient privileges?

> Unauthorized. '[my username]' does not have the required Kubernetes permissions to view this resource. Ensure you have the correct role/role binding for this user or group.

[image]

When creating the cluster, the `--aad-admin-group-object-ids` option was given the ID of an AD Group which is already used to manage another cluster, and I have sufficient privileges to view that cluster's resources.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to do, if you haven't already:

1. Enable Azure RBAC on your existing AKS cluster, using:

> ```
> az aks update -g myResourceGroup -n myAKSCluster --enable-azure-rbac
> ```

2. Add the necessary roles (Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role , Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader/Writer/Admin/Cluster Admin) to the user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac#create-role-assignments-for-users-to-access-cluster

Comment: Thanks, but having followed both of those steps I still don't have access. Furthermore, we have another existing AKS cluster to which I _do_ have access, and those steps have not been performed on that cluster.

Comment: Yes, this now works. I'm not sure why but the whole AKS set-up didn't appear correct, so I deleted the resource group and rebuilt everything. However, I do still have to run those two steps, yet our other cluster didn't need these.